# How do I hook up the wires for my double oven installation?

Tags: electrical, wiring, oven

I am installing a double oven. The wires from the oven are red, black, white and a ground. The wires in the junction box are two black and a ground.
All are 220V/240V.

What wire gets connected to what?

Comment: Unfortunate that appliance designers keep using 120V components in 240V appliances (which is the only reason it would need a white wire at all) given the availability of 240 clocks, etc. to serve the rest of the world market.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to replace the wire from the electrical panel to the junction box.  Your new oven requires a neutral (white) wire to power some 120v electronics in it.  Your existing wiring doesn't have that - it just has two hot wires for 240v.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate yes, indeed it does.  Editing...